# Django template table formatting

Tags: django

I am building a student test results template but am having a problem. Currently I have created 2 tests (Maths and Spelling) in my Tests model. The problem is, if I enter the data (scores) for the second test (Spelling) for a student first, the score get incorrectly placed in the template - the score gets placed in the Maths column and not the Spelling column. It gets corrected/moved into the spelling column as soon as I enter the same student’s name in the Maths test. It is a minor issue, but the result still is being put in the wrong place and I don’t know why.

I must be doing something wrong. I am missing some sort of filtering I guess. Hopefully the code below will help explain it further. Thanks.

## Models.py

```
    class Student(models.Model):
        first = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        last = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
        teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)

        def __unicode__(self):
              return "%s %s" % (self.first, self.last)


    class Test(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        Out_of = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

        class Meta:
            ordering = ['name']



    class Display(models.Model):
        name = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='art')
        test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
        one = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
        two = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
        three = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

# views.py
    def test(request):

    return list_detail.object_list(
          request,
          queryset = Student.objects.all(),
          template_name = 'display.html',
          template_object_name = 'results',

# display.html

    <table>

    <tr>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Maths</th>
        <th>Spelling</th>
    </tr>
    {% for item in results_list %}

    <tr>
              <td> {{ item.first }} </td>
              <td> {{ item.last }} </td>

        {% for x in item.art.all %}
              <td> {{ x.one }} </td>

        {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}
        </tr>

    </table>

# admin.py
    class StudentInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = Display


    class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        inlines = [StudentInline]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you need to somehow order the `item.art.all()` in same order that of your table columns (ie. math numbers  and then spelling). Also need to handle cases when only one of the test result is added.
But there isn't straight forward way of achieving this, you can't have foreign key (or relationship) member for `ordering` in `Meta` class.

So can have a method in your `Display` model to return list in preferred order and call it from template.

Sample solution below:

```
class Student(models.Model):
        first = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        last = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
        teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)
    def __unicode__(self):
          return "%s %s" % (self.first, self.last)

    #this would return in order as math, spelling
    def get_result_list_in_order(self):
        rlist = []
        for tname in ['math', 'spelling']:
            rtest = self.art.filter(test__name__iexact=tname)
            if rtest:
               rlist.append(rtest[0])  #add the first entry from filtered queryset
               # or do
               #rlist.extend(rtest)
            else
               rlist.append(None)

        return rlist
```

So what you can in template is

```
{% for x in item.get_result_list_in_order %}
    <td> {{x.one}} </td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan for the reply. I have tried your solution and all I get is a blank table. I made sure to spell the names in this line of the code properly and still no luck for tname in ['math', 'spelling']:. A question won't x.name return the name of the test to the template and not the number, which is stored in x.one?

Comment: @TomFin, oh yes, that should be `{{x.one}}`. Are your test names exactly match 'math' and 'spelling'?

Comment: @TomFin, Also, the method should be in `Student` not `Display` see the updated code now.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. As suggested I have made the changes. I still can't get it to work for some reason. I have placed an assert False to display the variable values and this is what they are: tname 'Spelling'
self <Student: Jack Smith>
rlist [[<Display: Display object>], [<Display: Display object>]] 
rtest [<Display: Display object>]
I know I have spelt the names correctly as proven here. I just can't get the test values to show up. They are still blank. I can only return something if I do {{ x }}. It simply returns [<Display: Display object>] in every table cell.

Comment: @TomFin Does the `Display` object has value in 'one`? Also try printing `rtest.one` in for loop of added function. Value printed there and in table should match.

Comment: yes the Display object has values in one for the students. Upon testing I noticed that it works for either maths or spelling depending on which is last in the set up list, if I return rtest and not rlist. I think the problem is if you return rlist in its current state it returns a list inside another list. But the template is expecting a single list. So how can I accomplish this?

Comment: @TomFin, ohh yes! `.filter()` gives you a list and we are trying to add that in our list. But we need to `extend` the list by `rlist.extend(rtest)`. See the updated code of function